# Test rest api method with parameter in JMeter

Tags: api, parameter-passing, jmeter, load-testing

I'm building load tests for a web API, and I can't get one of them to work.

The url is something like `http://myserver/myapp/mymethod` and it calls a java method like `public void mymethod(mytype param)`

And I don't know how to pass that param...

I'm getting this error:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Cannot consume content type).
```

EDIT:

I've tried setting `Content-Type = "application/json"` and passing a json parameter but now the server says:  `An error occured while trying to do a POST request.: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server`

The parameter, which is correct and I can get the values when debugging the webservice is:

```
{
"email": "name@server.com", 
"login": "name", 
"password": "1234"
}
```

Comment: You need to understand how the layer between HTTP and Java works, is it Spring-MVC ? or something else ?

Comment: It's a webservice with ejb...

Comment: But is it soap or rest ? if rest is it get or post ?...

Comment: It is rest and it is post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was just to pass a json parameter.

My class had the following properties:

```
private String email;
private String login;
private String password;
```

So I only needed to build a json object like:

```
{
"email": "name@server.com", 
"login": "name", 
"password": "1234"
}
```

and pass it as a parameter to the HTTP Request, with an empty name.